# Insert several regression lines from a table into a plot with the function abline

Tags: r, regression

I would like to generate a plot that shows 500 different regression lines. The intercept and slope values of the regression lines were determined before and and are in a table. You can see the first rows of the table below.

I can create a basic plot with the following code

```
plot(x=NA, type="n", ylim=c(1, 9), xlim=c(1, 4),
 xlab="x-lab", ylab="y-lab")
```

With function abline I can add individual regressions to the plot. For example like this:

```
abline(a=4.951170, b=0.8342761, col="red")
```

But how can I automatically add the 500 different values a (intercept) and b (slope) from the table to the plot? The aim is then to generate a plot that shows all 500 regression lines.
Greetings

| n | Intercept | Slope |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 5.577343 | 0.5459211 |
| 16 | 5.421676 | 0.6770537 |
| 16 | 5.056463 | 0.8671691 |
| 16 | 4.495589 | 1.0685088 |
| 16 | 5.527734 | 0.5559211 |
| 16 | 5.432168 | 0.7770537 |
| 16 | 5.156463 | 0.9671691 |
| 16 | 4.595589 | 1.1685088 |
| 16 | 5.477343 | 0.6459211 |
| 16 | 5.321676 | 0.5770537 |
| 16 | 5.156463 | 0.9671691 |
| 16 | 4.395589 | 1.1685088 |

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop can save you

```
df=data.frame(
  "intercept"=rnorm(5),
  "slope"=rnorm(5)
)

plot(x=NA, type="n", ylim=c(1, 9), xlim=c(1, 4),
     xlab="x-lab", ylab="y-lab")

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  abline(coef=df[i,])
}
```